# Embed a Vimeo video in a Excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, video, vimeo

How to Embed a Vimeo video in a Excel spreadsheet?

The process I'm following is:

1. Go to developer tabs and insert a shockwave flash object, from "More Controls"
2. In the properties of that object, insert the URL in "Movie". For example: https://player.vimeo.com/video/175816011

But this is returning a black rectangle, no video.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Any specific reason for embedding a video in Excel?

Comment: That's my business

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the URL ***is not*** a shockwave flash object. It's a web page that uses JavaScript to play the video. Excel doesn't understand the web page or JavaScript when it's looking for a Flash object.

Digging around the web page source and the JavaScript reveals a URL for a Flash object at https://player.vimeo.com/moog/175816011. Try that URL or https://f.vimeocdn.com/p/flash/moogaloop/6.4.3/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=175816011 with Excel. These two URLs may not work in the future if Vimeo changes the web page.

Comment: Bingo! http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=175816011 is :-) Thank you!